# Expressing the difference of a big rectangle and countably many small disjoint rectangles inside it as a countable disjoint union of rectangles.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, measure-theory

Let $R=[0,1)\times[0,1)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be a square and $\{R_i\}_{i\in \mathbf{N}}$ be countable collection of disjoint rectangles inside $R$, that is, $R_i=[p_i,q_i)\times[r_i,s_i)\subseteq R$ for all $i \in \mathbf{N}$ and $R_i \cap R_j=\emptyset$ for all $i \neq j$. Can we always express $R\setminus \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}R_i$ as a countable disjoint union or rectangles of the same form as the $R_is$?

While it seems intuitively obvious that it can be done, I cannot find a rigorous proof. My idea was to extend all sides of every small rectangle $R_i$ thus obtaining a finer partition of the big rectangle $R$ into countably many rectangles. The key problem is that one cannot order countably many points (at least not while preserving the usual order) and so it is far from obvious how one can identify the endpoints of the rectangles in the finer partition. Additionally, when we project the endpoints of the sides of the rectangles onto the axes, we might get a large number of accumulation points, which further complicates the task. These problems make me wonder if my question can be answered in the affirmative in general.

Comment: This is not true. For a counterexample you can use the (modified) construction of the Cantor set. Namely, you can exclude $[1/3,2/3)\times[0,1)$, then $[1/9,2/9)\times[0,1)$ and $[7/9,8/9)\times[0,1)$, and so on. (At each step exclude the middle stripes of the remaining parts.) The set obtained in the end cannot be expressed as a countable disjoint union of rectangles.

Comment: You are right! Thank you for your help!